# Get Road coordination From google api using geocode

Tags: google-maps

using google map api i want to get path of road using just the address
what i have made so far

> code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var geocoder;
        var map;
        var   infoWindow;

    function initMap() {
     geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 8,
        center: {lat: 0, lng: -180},
       });

     /* var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
      });*/
      codeAddress();
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;


    }
    function codeAddress() {
         geocoder.geocode( { 'address':  "my adress goes here"}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log(results);
            var obj1={lat:results[0].geometry.bounds.j.H,lng:results[0].geometry.bounds.H.H};
            var obj2={lat:results[0].geometry.bounds.H.j,lng:results[0].geometry.bounds.j.j};
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title:"my address "
            });

          } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
          }
        });
      }


        </script>
```

what i need is to get start of the address and the end so that i can use polyline using google api any idea how to achieve this, thank you

Answer (score 0):

> What I need is to get start of the address and the end so that i can use polyline using google api any idea how to achieve this?

You can make use of google.maps.Polyline({params});

From the [Map sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple):

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {lat: 0, lng: -180},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
    {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
    {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
    {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}
```

Additional reading from the [Maps Polyline docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polylines):

*Polylines*

To draw a line on your map, use a polyline. The Polyline class defines a linear overlay of connected line segments on the map. A Polyline object consists of an array of LatLng locations, and creates a series of line segments that connect those locations in an ordered sequence.

*Add a polyline*

The Polyline constructor takes a set of PolylineOptions specifying the LatLng coordinates of the line and a set of styles to adjust the polyline's visual behavior.

Polyline objects are drawn as a series of straight segments on the map. You can specify custom colors, weights, and opacities for the stroke of the line within the PolylineOptions when constructing your line, or you can change those properties after construction. A polyline supports the following stroke styles:

- *strokeColor* specifies a hexadecimal HTML color of the format "#FFFFFF". The Polyline class does not support named colors.
- *strokeOpacity* specifies a numerical value between 0.0 and 1.0 to determine the opacity of the line's color. The default is 1.0.
  strokeWeight specifies the width of the line in pixels.
  The polyline's editable property specifies whether users can edit the shape

Comment: i don't have start nor the end of the address i have only the address, what can i do ?

Comment: You need a starting location and a destination at least.

Comment: google does that but i don't know how see this when you type an address of road example "Clark Tce, SEATON" in google you get this kind of result [this](http://imgur.com/NHRDOKZ)